# For every $\epsilon>0$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that $\int_A|f(x)|\mu(dx) < \epsilon$ whenever $\mu(A) < \delta$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Hello all mathematicians!! Again, I am struggling with solving the exercises in Lebesgue Integral for preparing the quiz. At this moment, I and my friend are handling this problem, but both of us agreed this problem is a bit tricky.
The problem is following.

Let ($X,\mathcal{A},\mu$) be a measure space and suppose $\mu$ is $\sigma$-finite. Suppose $f$ is integrable. Prove that given $\epsilon$ there exist $\delta$ such that

$$
\int_A |f(x)|\mu(dx) \;\;<\;\;\epsilon
$$

whenever $\mu(A) < \delta$.

Could anybody give some good idea for us? Think you very much for your suggestion in advance.

Comment: The integrability of $f$ makes the $\sigma$-finiteness unnecessary.

Comment: How it is unnessary? I think I have to split the $X$ into disjoint sets by definition of $\sigma$ finite. Could you develop in detail for us?

Comment: Consider $S_n:=\{|f|\geqslant \frac 1n\}$: these sets are of finite measure and you can integrate over $\bigcup_n S_n$.

Comment: It's what Davide Giraudo said above. In other words, you can restrict your measure to the set where $f \neq 0$, which is $\sigma$-finite.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Hint:
$$
\int_A|f|\leqslant x\mu(A)+\int_{\{|f|\gt x\}}|f|\qquad\&\qquad\lim_{x\to\infty}\int_{\{|f|\gt x\}}|f|=0$$

Comment: I understand the first part. However, what if x on the first part goes to $\infty$? And for the second part, I don't get the exact meaning of $\{|f|>x \}$. Could you expalain more in detail? Thank you for your answer!

Comment: Ah! I am correcting the question for the second part. I want to ask how the second part does work. Thanks for the idea.

Comment: @BlockJeong: $x$ does not have to go to $\infty$. You just have to take it fixed, but big enough, so that $\int_{\{|f|>x\}} |f|$ is small (i.e.: $<\varepsilon/2$). Then, take $\delta$ such that $x \delta < \varepsilon/2$.

Comment: +1. This is a very elegant solution but I have a question. How do you justify in a simple manner that $$\int_{|f|>x} |f| \to 0?$$ The proof that I know uses Chebyshev's inequality to establish $\mu(\{|f| > x\}) \to 0$, and the absolute continuity of the integral--the very property the OP is trying to prove--to establish $\int_{|f| > x} |f| \to 0$.

Comment: @UmbertoP. Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem.

Comment: Of course. Thanks @Did

Answer (score 18):

If $f$ is integrable there exists a simple function $0 \le \phi \le f$ with the property that $$\int f - \phi \, d\mu < \frac{\epsilon}{2}.$$ Write $$\phi = \sum_{k=1}^n c_k \chi_{C_k}.$$ Since
$$ \int_A \phi \, d\mu = \sum_k c_k \mu(A \cap C_k) \le \mu(A) \sum_{k=1}^n c_k$$
you can take $$\delta = \frac{\epsilon}{2 \sum _{k=1}^n c_k}$$ to conclude $$\mu(A) < \delta \implies \int_A f \, d\mu  \le \int (f-\phi) \, d\mu  + \int_A \phi \, d\mu< \epsilon.$$

Comment: BTW if each $c_k = 0$ the proof is done at line 1.

Comment: This solution is the best I found!

Comment: @Tony Interesting. Why?

Comment: @Did, simplicity.

Comment: @RichardClare Hmmm... but there is an even simpler approach, neatly so.

Answer (score 3):

Define the sequence $A_n=\{|f|\geq n\}$ (the set of all the points in which the value of $|f|$ is greater or equal than $n$). Since $f$ is integrable, clearly $|f|$ is measurable and therefore $A_n$ is measurable for any $n$. $A_n$ is defined a.e. (as $f$ is); should it sound odd to you, since everything holds up to a.e. equivalence, you could replace $f$ with any representative of its equivalence class.

Obviously $A_n$ is decreasing ($A_n\supseteq A_{n+1}$ for any $n$), therefore there exists the limit
$$
A_\infty\dot=\lim_{n\to\infty}A_n=\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty A_n
$$
and $A_\infty$ is measurable. From the integrability of $f$ it follows that $\mu(A_\infty)=0$ (if $\mu(A_\infty)>0$ then $\int_X |f|{\rm d}\mu \geq \int_{A_\infty}|f|{\rm d}\mu = \infty \cdot \mu(A_\infty) = \infty$, so $f$ would not be integrable).

Therefore the sequence
$$
f_n ~\dot=~ f\chi_{A_n}
$$
converges to $0$ a.e. ($\chi_{A_n}$ is the [indicator function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function) of the set $A_n$). It is not difficult to argue that $f_n$ is measurable for any $n$.

Now apply Lebesgue's [dominated convergence theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem) to $f_n$ which is pointwise less or equal than $|f|$, which is integrable.

Therefore
$$
\int_{A_n}f_n{\rm d}\mu ~\stackrel{n\to\infty}{\longrightarrow} 0
$$
It should be easy from here... :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Does it hold $|f(x)| < \infty$ if $f$ is integrable? No possibility that $|f| = infty$ even though $f$ is integrable?

Comment: I edited the answer. Remember that we are in terms of "almost everywhere"... in this sense, for instance, the function $\infty\cdot\chi_{\mathbb Q}$ is integrable wrt Lebesgue measure in $\mathbb R$, and $A_\infty=\mathbb Q$ which is non-empty but has null measure.

Comment: Your $A_n$ is not arbitrary.

Answer (score 1):

This is my full solution based on the hint from the top answer:

Let $f$ be integrable and let $\epsilon > 0$ be arbitrary. We know that $$\lim_{\alpha\to\infty}\int_{\{|f|\geq \alpha\}}|f| d\mu=0$$
Thus, we can take $\alpha$ big enough so that $$\int_{\{|f|\geq \alpha\}}|f|  d\mu < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$$
Fix $\delta = \dfrac{\epsilon}{2\alpha}$ and let $A$ be such that $\mu(A) < \delta$. We have that:
\begin{align*}
\int_{A}|f| d\mu 
&= \int_{A}|f| \cdot I_{\{|f|< \alpha\}} d\mu + \int_{A}|f| \cdot I_{\{|f|\geq \alpha\}} d\mu \\
&\leq \alpha \cdot \mu(A) + \int_{A \cap \{|f|\geq \alpha\}}|f| d\mu \\
&\leq \alpha \cdot \mu(A) + \int_{\{|f|\geq \alpha\}}|f| d\mu \\
&< \alpha \cdot \frac{\epsilon}{2\alpha} + \frac{\epsilon}{2} \\
&=\epsilon
\end{align*}