# $\forall \epsilon >0, \exists \sigma >0$ such as : $ [\forall A\in F : P(A)<\sigma ]\Rightarrow [\int_A |x| dP $

Tags: probability, integration, measure-theory, conditional-expectation

Let $(\Omega, F,P) $ be probability space.

If $X\in L^1(\Omega)$ , show that:
$\forall \epsilon >0, \exists \sigma >0$ such that:
$$
[\forall A\in F : P(A)<\sigma ]\Rightarrow   [\int_A |x| dP
$$

Comment: To complete the proof you need an additional step to justify why having probability zero will give the result. Hint: it is related to putting the limit inside the integral.

Comment: Your statement as it appears seems incomplete.

Comment: Take a look at [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/513401/36150)