# Tail of an integrable function

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ be an integrable function. Then for every $\epsilon>0$, there exists a compact set $K$ depending on $\epsilon$ such that
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}^n\setminus K}|f|<\epsilon.
$$
I am curious to know if the above compact set $K$ can be chosen arbitrarily small.

Can someone please explain in detail? Thank you.

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/513401/121671) with a little extra effort on your part you can get what you need from the link.

Comment: Thanks, but still its bothering me, if its possible or not to choose small measure $K$. Note here the integration is outside $K$.

Comment: You compact set has to be "large" enough to contain most of the mass over which $f$ is integrable. That is why the statement is as it is. If your $K$ is small (in mass) you region of integration approaches the whole support of $f$.

Comment: Thats what I also thought. So the compact set $K$ cannot be small in measure in the question, right?

Comment: If you want to make the integral of over the complement. no your $K$ cannot be made small (relative to the support of $f$).